# Limiting Broadcast Receiver for Fragment only

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, fragment, android-broadcastreceiver

I have created a BroadCast Receiver to notify the GPS state as below :

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "asdsadasdsaD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Receiver in Manifest as below :

```
 <receiver android:name=".utility.GpsLocationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Now, the issue is that What if I want to check gps state only in single Fragment ? Right now it broadcasting for overall app.

Thanks.

Comment: try to use LocalBroadcastManager for your problem here is the [DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496786/android-how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

Answer (score 0):

**ReceiverActivity.java**

A Activity that watches for notifications for the event named "custom-event-name"

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 ...

// Register to receive messages.
// We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
// with actions named "custom-event-name".
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
  new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
 @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent
   String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
   Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
 }
};

  @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
   // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
   .unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
   super.onDestroy();
   }
```

**SenderActivity.java**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

in OnResume() of your fragment write

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(gpsChangeReceiver , new IntentFilter("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"));
```

An in onPause() of your fragment write

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(gpsChangeReceiver );
```

At bottom of your fragment write

```
private BroadcastReceiver gpsChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "asdsadasdsaD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Its not calling anywhere with above code you suggested.